# OpenMPI IPC performance is worse than reading/writing to file

Tags: performance, fortran, ipc, openmpi

I am trying out various ways of IPC to do the following:

1. Master starts.
2. Master starts a slave.
3. Master passes an array to slave.
4. Slave processes the array.
5. Slave sends the array back to master.

I have tried using OpenMPI to solve this by having the parent process spawn a child which in turn does the aforementioned processing. However, I have also tried - what I thought would be the worst possible way to do this - letting master write the data to a file and have slave read and write back to that file. *The result is stunning.*

Below is the two ways in which I achieve this. The first way is the "file" way, the second one is by using OpenMPI.

Master.f90

```
program master
implicit none

integer*4, dimension (10000) :: matrix
integer :: length, i, exitstatus, cmdstatus
logical :: waistatus

! put integers in matrix and output data into a file 
open(1, file='matrixdata.dat', status='new')

length = 10000

do i=1,length
    matrix(i) = i
    write(1,*) matrix(i)
end do

close(1)

call execute_command_line("./slave.out", wait = .true., exitstat=exitstatus)

if(exitstatus .eq. 0) then
    ! open and read the file changed by subroutine slave
    open(1, file= 'matrixdata.dat', status='old')
    do i = 1, length
        read(1,*) matrix(i)
    end do
    close(1)
endif

end program master
```

Slave.f90

```
program slave
implicit none

    integer*4, dimension (10000) :: matrix
    integer :: length, i

    ! Open and read the file made by master into a matrix
    open (1, file= 'matrixdata.dat', status = 'old')
    length = 10000

    do i = 1, length
        read(1,*) matrix(i)
    end do
    close(1)

    ! Square all numbers and write over the file with new data
    open(1, file= 'matrixdata.dat', status = 'old')
    do i=1,length
        matrix(i) = matrix(i)**2
        write(1,*) matrix(i)
    end do
    close(1)

end program slave
```

*** OpenMPI ***

Master.f90

```
program master
use mpi
implicit none

    integer :: ierr, num_procs, my_id, intercomm, i, siz, array(10000000), s_tag, s_dest, siffra

    CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)

    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)

    siz = 10000

    !print *, "S.Rank =", my_id
    !print *, "S.Size =", num_procs

    if (.not. (ierr .eq. 0)) then
        print*, "S.Unable to initilaize bös!"
        stop
    endif

    do i=1,size(array)
        array(i) = 2
    enddo

    if (my_id .eq. 0) then
        call MPI_Comm_spawn("./slave.out", MPI_ARGV_NULL, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, my_id, &
        & MPI_COMM_WORLD, intercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE, ierr)


        s_dest = 0 !rank of destination (integer)
        s_tag =  1 !message tag (integer)
        call MPI_Send(array(1), siz, MPI_INTEGER, s_dest, s_tag, intercomm, ierr)

        call MPI_Recv(array(1), siz, MPI_INTEGER, s_dest, s_tag, intercomm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)

        !do i=1,10
        !   print *, "S.Array(",i,"): ", array(i)
        !enddo

    endif

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

end program master
```

Slave.f90

```
program name
use mpi
implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    integer :: ierr, parent, my_id, n_procs, i, siz, array(10000000), ctag, csource, intercomm, siffra
    logical :: flag

    siz = 10000

    ! executable statements
    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Initialized(flag, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_get_parent(parent, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, n_procs, ierr)

    csource = 0 !rank of source
    ctag = 1 !message tag

    call MPI_Recv(array(1), siz, MPI_INTEGER, csource, ctag, parent, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)

    !do i=1,10
    !    print *, "C.Array(",i,"): ", array(i)
    !enddo

    do i=1,size(array)
        array(i) = array(i)**2
    enddo

    !do i=1,10
    !    print *, "C.Array(",i,"): ", array(i)
    !enddo

    call MPI_Send(array(1), siz, MPI_INTEGER, csource, ctag, parent, ierr)

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program name
```

Now, the interesting part is that by using the `time` program I have measured that it takes 19.8 ms to execute the "file version of the program". The OpenMPI version takes 60 ms. Why? Is there really so much overhead in OpenMPI that it is faster to read/write to file if you're working with <400 KiB?

I tried increasing the array to 10^5 integers. The file version executes in 114ms, OpenMPI in 53ms. When increasing to 10^6 integers file: 1103 ms, OpenMPI: 77ms.

Is the overhead really that much?

Comment: You got an MPI time of 60 ms. Then, you _increased_ the array size and the MPI time went _down_ to 53 ms!? These array sizes are too small to measure accurately with the `time` command. When I do this, I embed the timing/benchmark into the code itself and use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,...)` before and after, repeat the runs about 10 times and use the smallest time to negate startup issues, timeslicing issues.

Comment: Use the `newunit` specifier in your `open` statement to avoid nasty clashes.  Manually setting connected file units is extremely error prone and difficult to maintain in larger programs.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, it doesn't make sense to use distributed processing for problem sizes that fit in cache (except in some trivially parallel cases). The typical usage scenario is for data transfer much larger than LLC. Even you biggest case (10^6) fits in modern caches.

Firstly, for the method of writing to disk, you have to be aware of the influence of a page cache in your operating system. If your MPI processes are on the same chip, the operating system just hears 'do a write' then 'do a read'. If, in the interim, nothing pollutes the page cache then it will just fetch the data from RAM as oppose to the disk.  A better experiment would be to flush the page cache between the write and read (this is possible, at least on linux, via a shell command). In effect you are performing shared memory processing if you're grabbing the data from the page cache.

Also, you are using `time` on the command line so you're incorporating the time it takes for MPI to initialize and establish communication interfaces with a few function calls. This is not a good benchmark because the interface provided for disk IO method has already been initialized by the operating system.  Also for such a small problem size, the initialization of MPI is nontrivial compared to the runtime of the body of the program. The proper way to do this is to do the timing in the code.

For both methods, you should expect linear scaling biased by the overhead of the method.  In fact, you should see a few regimes as the data size surpasses LLC and page cache. The best way to do this is to repeat your runs with ARRAY_SIZE=2^n for n=12,13,..24 and check out the curve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, if i may ask, how would _you_ solve as issue like this? If we are talking about transfering data between processes where the data is between 1kiB to 100 kiB, how would you do that?

Comment: If you're doing distributed processing you'd use MPI, but if you're using distributed processing to improve performance, as oppose to increase capability (i.e. increase available memory), you really have to evaluate if it is the appropriate model to implement your code or algorithm.